# Only numbers on type text input on React.js with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to avoid any type of string when entering an input. I found a code here on stack overflow which works. However it only works when a number is entered first, or if I put a letter and delete all; it does not work when typing the first letter. And I didn't understand the code that well. I don't even know what is /^[0-9\b]+$/

**Here is the code**

```
   const [value, setValue] = useState();

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
        if (e.target.value === "" || re.test(e.target.value)) {
            setValue(e.target.value);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you heard of regular expression? `/^[0-9\b]+$/` is one of them. It is basically a set of rules to match a particular pattern of text.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and then you can test with https://regexr.com/ they also have a cheat sheet

Comment: [RegExp documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: If you only want to work with numbers, why are you entering letters? It's unclear if you have an issue with code you are trying to use, or if you are just asking how some code you found on the internet works.

Answer (score 0):

How about testing if conversion to Number returns NaN? Try code below:

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState();

 const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (!isNaN(Number(e.target.value))) {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }
 };
```

And, btw, as guys in the comments below the original question correctly pointed out, this: `/^[0-9\b]+$/` is indeed a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
const [input, setinput] = useState('')
const handleInput = (value) => {
    if (isNaN(value)) return
     setinput(value)
}
return (
    <>
        <input value={input} onChange={e => handleInput(e.target.value)} />
    </>
)
```

Comment: You should add explanation.